# Is it possible to get Network Domain from Client with PHP or Apache?

Tags: php, apache, networking, dns, access-control

I'm working on a solution to identify client Network Domain or Workgroup in a private network. Based on it, I must change some access permissions.

I can't do that through IP address because it isn't trustable, only network domain/ workgroup.

For reasons unknown to me I can't have a login screen, access must be automatic and seamless.

Someone know how can I do it?

Comment: you want an apache site to determine what domain a remote user is in? that is NOT going to be available via http, and even IE long ago stopped sending out user credentials nillywilly to anyone who asked.

Comment: I want determine where the client is comming...
 Eg.
 - domain.global.machine-name: Show global data 
 - domain.localA.machine-name: Show localA data

Comment: so dns domain, or windows domain?

Comment: The target is dns Domain, tested here with gethostbyaddr  and Its returns complete name of machine eg: Workspace1/Machine1

Inside a VPN I got a different name: zone1.subzoneB.networkA.machine2

Over internet I got reverse IP eg: 172-131-12-21.companyname.net


Well, you must be over same network to get access to Name Service.

Domains are a little above on OSI Layer, and Is a little difficult to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to get corresponding to a given IP address using `gethostbyaddr` function http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyaddr.php:

```
    $proxy = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] : false;

if(!!$proxy){
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
     echo "Warning: Your cliend is using proxy, may could not determine hostname";
    }else{
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; //
    }
    $hostname = gethostbyaddr($ipaddress); //Its will return domain + machine-name inside a private network.

    if($ipaddress  == $hostname){
     echo "Impossible to determine hostname for: ", $ipaddress ;
    }else{
      echo "The hostname for ", $ipaddress, "is : ",  $hostname;
    }
```

But the communication using application / session layer to network layer is a little complicated. You must don't trust it to access control in php applications.

To get all public IP Address is possible to use [WebRTC](https://github.com/diafygi/webrtc-ips) (javascript) instead remote addrees from http header.

Comment: op wants windows domain, not hostname. hostname is easy. domain is near impossible.

Comment: I don't know how trustable is it.

Comment: In a local network with linux and windows machines I get machine name... in a domain local private network I got the full name, something like: "net1.zoneA.localmachine-name"

Comment: Funny, over internet the reverse IP is returned, take a look on [Running Example](http://www.leonancarvalho.com/projects/info.php)